# Acknowledgment as technician. Do I list them in the CV? How?

Tags: cv, acknowledgement, non-academic-staff

I’m a technician that has done some work in a research group, and I get some acknowledgments in the papers. A fellow technician in the university has told me that for us, technicians, they are important for our CV, as we don’t get publications (we usually just assist, so getting in a publication is really weird).

Should I put my acknowledgments in my CV? If so, how should I put them? I tried to put them with the name of the paper and the authors, but maybe my future employer won’t understand that part if he is not in academia (but e.g., in a company).

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the CV of the person who suggested this to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employers outside academia usually aren't interested in publications but rather in your abilities and any deliverables you can associate those abilities with.

How specifically you highlight those abilities completely depends on the job you are applying for. For example, if you were applying for a position where you would be doing LC/MS, you could write in your resume that you "processed LC/MS samples in support of three projects leading to publishable papers."

If you were applying for an academic job, I'd be more likely to suggest including the papers your were acknowledged in, along with a note about what you were acknowledged for.